# collision between a particle array and a box

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision, particles

Im working on a school project and I need to get collision between an array of particles and a box, here is my current code:

```
for(var i : int = 0; i < particles.length; i++)
{
    particles[i].update();

    if(Particle.hitTestPoint(Square))
    {
        particle = particles.shift();
        particle.destroy();
    }
}
```

I get an error telling me that im trying to call an undefined method (hittestpoint) through a reference with static type class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank!

Here is the code for the Particle.

```
package
```

{
    import flash.display.*;

```
public class Particle
{
    public var clip : DisplayObject;

    public var xVel : Number = 0;
    public var yVel : Number = 0;

    public var drag : Number = 1;

    public var gravity : Number = 0.0;
    public var shrink : Number = 1;
    public var fade : Number = 0;
    public function Particle(symbolclass : Class, target : DisplayObjectContainer, xpos : Number, ypos : Number)
    {
        clip = new symbolclass();

        target.addChild(clip);

        clip.x= xpos;
        clip.y= ypos;

    }       
    public function update() : void
    {
        clip.x += xVel;
        clip.y += yVel;

        xVel *= drag;
        yVel *= drag;


        yVel+=gravity;

        clip.scaleX *= shrink;
        clip.scaleY *= shrink;

        clip.alpha -= fade;
    }
    public function destroy() :void
    {
        clip.parent.removeChild(clip);
    }

}
```

}

I used [this tutorial](http://www.computerarts.co.uk/tutorials/cool-particle-effects-flash) for the particles, and my goal is to add collision to them

Comment: In the first line in the loop, you refer to `particles[i]`, but then you refer to `Particle` or `particle`. Why don't you just try to be more consistent, and see what happens?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I made the change and it comes up with an error saying property hittestpoint not found on Particle

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Updated my answer now that `Particle` code was posted.

Your `Particle` class doesn't define `hitTestPoint`.  In addition to that, you are calling a static method which I don't think you want here... you want an instance method.

Make sure you define `hitTestPoint` in your `Particle` class.  Then, instead of `Particle.hitTestPoint`, try `particle.hitTestPoint` (note upper case, which refers to the class is changed to lower-case which refers to the instance.

Try this:

```
for(var i : int = 0; i < particles.length; i++)
{
    var particle:Particle = particles[i];
    particles.update();

    if(particle.hitTestPoint(Square))
    {
        particle = particles.shift();
        particle.destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: That definitely makes sense, I tried it with the changes you suggested and paying close attention to the capitalization, still getting an error saying "call to an undefined method" source is (particle.hitTestPoint(Square)).

Comment: @FieryAvocado Well, you posted your `Particle` class, which is great... but there is one problem... `Particle` does not define a function called `hitTestPoint`.  That is your problem.  Editing my response.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get the program to work with your help!

Comment: @FieryAvocado Then make sure to mark the answer correct, please.

Answer (score 1):

The Particle class must extend MovieClip to have the hitTestPoint method. Try changing the class to:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
public class Particle extends MovieClip
{
    //code here
```

and import specific classes in your code (see MovieClip class as that's the one you are using and it's methods) for better results as good practice.

Comment: Both answers are correct. Note, that the `Particle` class doesn't have to extend `MovieClip` it can simply extend `DisplayObject` (that's where the `hitTestPoint()` method is defined).  Finally, when calling `hitTestPoint()` you should pass in the proper parameters, the method signature is: `hitTestPoint(x:Number, y:Number, shapeFlag:Boolean = false):Boolean`

Comment: CheeseWarlock  is also right: he needs to test object collision if "square" is an actual square object. Also you should pass at least x, y parameters when using hitTestPoint() method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `particle` refers to in that code since it's not defined in what you posted, but `particles[i]` is the particle you want to test.

Your `Particle` class doesn't have a `hitTestPoint` function- but it contains a `DisplayObject` that does. So with those two things in mind, you can call hit tests using `particles[i].clip.hitTestPoint`.

Next problem: you're trying to pass the *class* `Square` to the hitTest rather than an instance. And still, `hitTestPoint` takes a single point as its argument, not an object like what a square would represent. So you will probably want to use `hitTestObject` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was able to fix the program and got the collision working.